# Remove QuickTime logo while AirPlay

Tags: ios, ios7, quicktime, airplay

In my iOS app, I use MPMoviePlayerController for video playback. When I enable AirPlay, there is a QuickTime logo, which I would like to remove, superimposes on the AirPlay background.
It only happens with my app on iOS 7.0.4. On iOS versions prior to 7.0.4 such as 7.0.0 or 6.1, there is no QuickTime logo shown, the AirPlay background is displayed as usual.

[image: QuickTime logo on AirPlay background]

Anyone has any ideas why the QuickTime logo is there and how we could remove it?

To be clear, I used video content for playback, not audio-only content; and I'm talking about the background view when using AirPlay only.
Thanks!

Comment: looks like an iOS bug to me

Comment: do you find any solution?

Comment: @Diksha it was a bug of iOS and was fixed in a later version.

Comment: @ThanhPham the issue still persists in iOS 11 also,is there anything documented by apple regarding this issue?

Comment: This happened to me long time ago and I remember they fixed it on an iOS update after 7.0.4. I couldn't find anything doc'd at that time though.